# What are the correct permissions for Apache's 000-default.conf?

Tags: permissions, apache2

I just recently created my first VPS and installed a LAMP stack with Wordpress. I noticed that `000-default.conf` in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` has `777` permissions. This seems suspect to me. Not sure how it got this way. Is this a problem, and what are the correct permissions?

Answer (score 1):

My server has `000-default.conf` with `0644` (`-rw-r--r--`) permissions in `sites-available` and as a symlink `lrwxrwxrwx` in `sites-enabled`.

You should check the permissions of the file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` to make sure it's something sane (at least not world-writable) as the link permissions don't matter (accessing the file through the link uses the target file's permissions)

Answer (score 0):

Using `ls -l` I have shown `000-default.conf` is owned by `root` with `-rw-r--r--`

```
root@ubuntu:~# cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/
root@ubuntu:/etc/apache2/sites-available# ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1332 Mar 19  2016 000-default.conf
```

This was tested for Apache 2.4.18

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/apache2/sites-available# apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2018-04-18T14:53:04
```